# Select to join two tables with replace function/ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got two tables:

```
Table_promo
Name   | Code    | 
Promo1 | 123     |
Promo2 | 124     |
Promo3 | 125     |
```

And second table:

```
Table_invoice
Index  | Promo   | Price
1155   | 123+    | 1.25
2754   | 125K    | 3.26
2378   | 124+    | 2.28
```

I need select that will give me every index from table_invoice with name of the promo from table_promo. The problem is that in table_invoice there are chars '+' or 'K' at the end of the promo number so I can't simply compare promo codes between two tables.
I've tried writing a select subquery like that:

```
(select name from table_promo where table_promo.code=to_number(replace(replace(table_invoice.promo,'+',''),'K','')
```

to replace every '+' and 'K' with empty char ''
It doesn't work, I get error

```
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
```

I think that the problem is with converting data in table_invoice.promo and table_promo.code
I've tried converting both to_number, both to_char and using the 'like' clausule between, nothing helps
I am sure that there is another way to delete this chars from table_invoice.promo in this select and compare it to table_promo.code, but can't get any info in the internet

Comment: It's unclear what you want.  Even if the subquery that you posted returned the results you want it to, it would still return multiple rows, thus giving you the same error.

Comment: @tilper I need to get every index from invoice with the name of the promo that index belongs to. So I need to remove the '+' or 'K' from invoice.promo and find the code in table_promo

Comment: As @tilper said, the issue is not the subquery itself, it's the fact that it's returning more than one row while the main query expect only one. It would help to see the whole query.

Answer (score 0):

Just use concatenation:

```
select . . .
from table_promo p join
     table_invoice i
     on i.promo = p.code || '+';
```

I think you want the inverse to handle `+` and `K`:

```
select . . .
from table_promo p join
     table_invoice i
     on p.promo like i.promo || '_'
```

In the meantime, you should fix the data model.  The connection to `code` should use an exact code.  You can store the `+` and `K` information in a separate column.

Comment: But the problem is that It's sometimes '+' and sometimes 'K'

Comment: @matuszek . . . That is not an issue.  The second query handles both.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from         table_promo p 
       join  table_invoice I
       on    regexp_substr (I.promo,'^\d+') =
             P.code
```

Comment: Logically this seems inefficient: if the engine decides that it is cheaper to pull rows from P first, and then compare to each row from I, then the regexp_substr() may need to be computed repeatedly. To avoid that, one could join to a subquery (instead of I) where the regexp_substr is calculated first. Wondering if the Optimizer would, in effect, do the same thing.

Comment: NESTED LOOP with table_promo as the outer table seems like the most unlikely option for this query. More likely HASH JOIN where  `table_promo` is the hashed table and `Table_invoice` is the streamed one.

Comment: @greybeard, absolutely not :-) Judging by the way this code was formatted and the lack of a fiddle, I conclude it was posted from my cellphone. I fixed the typo. Thanks!